# similar_search for physics units

Tags: php, search

I implemented the similar search very good. But there is one problem with units. Because units are prettey short the similar search is not that good.

I do create a recipe with:

```
1 kg Tomato
```

If the user is writing:

```
1 gk Tomato
```

the similar search is not that good. Is there a pretty fine way to do it? Right now I just use an array and compare the units. My array looks like this:

```
array(kg, gk, kilgramm)
```

If there is a match then take this unit. Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're looking at just a small number of terms, preferably short ones, you can use the [levenshtein](http://no.php.net/levenshtein) algorithm to find the cost of transforming one string into another. It's less expensive than similar_text, so if that works, levenshtein will probably work fine as well.